# C# custom attribute shorthad

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have an attribute with a fairly long/complex list of parameters. For example:
  `[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV","|DataDirectory|\\stores.csv","stores#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]`

Is there a way to create a custom attribute as a shorthand for this, so that instead of typing the above for every method, I can just use `[CustomDataSource]`?

Comment: The `DataSource` attribute is `sealed`, so you cannot inherit from it.  Any code looking for a `DataSource` attribute will not see your custom attribute.

Comment: If the issue is the length then use one of the overloads of `DataSource`

Comment: @amy, thanks. I figured that out the hard way. :). but is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Use constants instead of the strings.  Depending on the constant names, the code could look like `[DataSource(Constants.A, Constants.B, Constants.C, Constants.D)]`.  Substitute appropriate names.  Another alternative is to use something like PostSharp (not free).

Comment: If the repetitive typing is the biggest issue, select the text and drag it to the VS ToolBox.  Then you can just double-click it in the Toolbox list and it will be inserted at the current cursor position.  Alternatively, you could write a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataSource` attribute is sealed, you cannot inherit from it.

The easiest solution is to use constants:

```
public class Const
{
    public const string Provider = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV";
    public const string ConnString = "|DataDirectory|\\stores.csv";
    public const string Table = "stores#csv";
    public const string Method = DataAccessMethod.Sequential;
}

[DataSource(Const.Provider, Const.ConnString , Const.Table , Const.Method)]
```